# How do I query a permissions graph using gremlin?

Tags: graph, permissions, acl, gremlin, rbac

I have the following graph:

[image: permissions graph]

I'm using Tinkergraph to try and figure out:

1. Does *User#1* have "read" permission on *Resource#1*? (it does not)
2. Does *User#2* have "write" permission on *Resource#1*? (it does).

I'm also trying to find a query that's not specific to this exact graph, since in the real life model there may be multiple hierarchical roles in between.  I'm just starting to get to grips with the Gremlin syntax but this particular query I'm finding elusive.  Here's the code that creates the graph above:

```java
    Graph graph = TinkerGraph.open();
    Vertex user1 = graph.addVertex(T.label, "user", T.id, 1, "name", "marko");
    Vertex user2 = graph.addVertex(T.label, "user", T.id, 2, "name", "vadas");
    Vertex role1 = graph.addVertex(T.label, "role", T.id, 3, "name", "role_1");
    Vertex role2 = graph.addVertex(T.label, "role", T.id, 4, "name", "role_2");
    Vertex resource1 = graph.addVertex(T.label, "resource", T.id, 5, "name", "resource_1");
    Vertex resource2 = graph.addVertex(T.label, "resource", T.id, 6, "name", "resource_2");

    user1.addEdge("read", resource2, T.id, 7);
    user1.addEdge("member", role2, T.id, 8);
    user2.addEdge("owns", resource2, T.id, 9);
    user2.addEdge("member", role1, T.id, 10);

    role1.addEdge("child_of", role2, T.id, 11);
    role1.addEdge("read", resource1, T.id, 12);

    role2.addEdge("write", resource1, T.id, 13);
    role2.addEdge("write", resource2, T.id, 14);
```

My current attempt to answer question #1 was to use `repeat`, by starting with *User#1* and following paths until it found an "outEdge" with label "read" leading to vertex *Resource#1*.

Aahhh as I'm writing this I may have just figured it out, but as I'm pretty new to Gremlin maybe someone who knows Gremlin well can sanity check it or tell me if there's a better way to do it? And if not, then maybe this will help someone else who is trying to solve the same problem.

```java
q1 = graph.traversal().V(user1.id())
    .repeat(__.out().simplePath())
    .until(__.outE().hasLabel("read").inV().is(resource1)).path().toList();
// q1 returns [] (which is expected)

q2 = graph.traversal().V(user2.id())
    .repeat(__.out().simplePath())
    .until(__.outE().hasLabel("write").inV().is(resource1)).path().toList();
// q2 returns [[v[2], v[3], v[4]]]  (which seems right too)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't traverse arbitrary out edges (without label restrictions). I think you're looking for

1. a direct connection to the resource
2. a connection from the users role to the resource or
3. a connection from any parent role to the resource

The best way to cover all three cases in a single query is to start from the user, traverse all `member` and `child_of` edges, emit all the vertices along the path and ultimately check if there's a `read` / `write` connection from any of the vertices to the resource:

```
gremlin> // Does User#1 have "read" permission on Resource#1? (it does not)
gremlin> g.V(1).emit().
             repeat(out("member","child_of")).
           out("read").has("name","resource_1").hasNext()
==>false

gremlin> // Does User#2 have "write" permission on Resource#1? (it does).
gremlin> g.V(2).emit().
             repeat(out("member","child_of")).
           out("write").has("name","resource_1").hasNext()
==>true
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very useful tip about unrestricted labels and generally your query makes a lot more sense! ;)